# Recoll - Specifying width of results window

Tags: window, customization, recoll

How can I specify, *at startup from config file or environment parameter*, a **fixed width** to the display area window for search results reported by recoll ?

The dimension I am trying to control is marked up below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been redirected to developer who, [per his response](https://framagit.org/medoc92/recoll/-/issues/162), will pursue the issue.